# Running forward proxy over openvpn

Tags: networking, proxy, openvpn, nginx, squid

Where I live, there is quite a bit of censorship on the internet, and so I hope to be able to run a proxy on my home server which passes all my internet traffic through an openvpn tunnel, such that I can freely access blocked sites. My home server runs nginx, and my endgoal is to have a subdirectory from which i can access a specific blocked site. Has this been done before?

What i have tried:

I have tried setting up an nginx forward proxy, but the blocked website i wanted to access is uses cloudflare, and I kept getting Errors `503` & `1001`. From a bit of research, i found out that this was an SSL based error, and nginx did not have the capability to do this and i should move to `squid`.

My `squid` config looks like so:

```
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines


acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

acl first localip <IP_OF_INTERFACE_I_ACCESS_FROM>

tcp_outgoing_address <IP_OF_VPN_INTERFACE> first
#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# This default configuration only allows localhost requests because a more
# permissive Squid installation could introduce new attack vectors into the
# network by proxying external TCP connections to unprotected services.
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet

# The two deny rules below are unnecessary in this default configuration
# because they are followed by a "deny all" rule. However, they may become
# critically important when you start allowing external requests below them.

# Protect web applications running on the same server as Squid. They often
# assume that only local users can access them at "localhost" ports.
http_access deny to_localhost

# Protect cloud servers that provide local users with sensitive info about
# their server via certain well-known link-local (a.k.a. APIPA) addresses.
http_access deny to_linklocal

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# For example, to allow access from your local networks, you may uncomment the
# following rule (and/or add rules that match your definition of "local"):
# http_access allow localnet

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

tcp_outgoing_address 10.24.0.5 localnet

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

However, this does not work, as I can still see my ISP's block message when attempting to access the site through the proxy.

How should I go about achieving what I want to achieve? Is there another software I should use? TIA.

P.S. I've looked into Linux namespaces as well, and they do not fit my usecase.

Comment: Not an answer: Which country? Have you tried Outline (getoutline.org) and Lantern (lantern.io)?

Comment: Quite a bit to ask/unpack before this can really be answered.  You may want to explain your topography better.   Why don't you just change your routing so the traffic all goes through the vpn without using a proxy?   **Have you set up your browser to send requests through your proxy?**

Comment: @Gantendo  I live in south east asia. I also already have a vpn, but won't use it directly for reasons mentioned below.

Comment: @davidgo  for various reasons such as convenience and latency, I wish to only use the vpn when accessing this specific site. I don't wish to have to touch my browser settings to send traffic through my proxy, but rather access a specific subdirectory on my home server which will lead to the site through a vpn. However, for purposes of testing, yes, I have set up foxyproxy to direct all traffic through my proxy.